# Update a text field on PAGE-A using class length value from PAGE-B

Tags: javascript, jquery

PAGE-A

```
var count = $('.gjGroupUsersUser').children().length -= 1;
console.log(count);
```

This above works ok and in console on PAGE-A I get, let's say value 2

PAGE-B

Now, in PAGE-A when the oldVal of count (which is 2) changes, I need to get the newVal (let's say 3) in PAGE-B and update the field xfield, like

```
$('#count').on('change', function() {
var oldVal = $('#count').val();
  $('#xfield').val(oldVal);
setInterval(function(){ 
  var newVal = $('#count').val(); 
  if(newVal !== oldVal){
$('#xfield').val(newVal);
console.log(newVal, oldVal);
    oldVal = newVal;
  }
}, 100);

}).trigger( 'change' );
```

So xfield will get the newVal and in console on pageB will show values 3, 2

Maybe in order to get the count something like the following could work but I can't construct and pass the value...

```
    $.get('url', function(getcount){
     var newcount = $(getcount).find('div.gjGroupUsersUser').children().length -= 1;
```

Comment: Could you explain what your goal is and what you're trying to build here?

Comment: I need to get the value of count in page-b and update a text field in page-a when the value of count changes. In other words, the text field in page-a to remain updated with the value produced from count in page-b

Comment: I'm sorry. My question was not specific enough. What is the project that you're building? I'm asking this because you're looking for an answer for your solution, but it could be that your solution is not the correct one. Does one navigate from page A to page B or are A and B running simultaniously (like in different open tabs)?

Comment: Your question is correct. Page-A and Page-B both belong to CB (community builder) where Page-A is the edit user profile or the profile view and Page-B is the groups page (CB's add-on called Groupjive) and specifically the users tab.  var count shows the number of users in a specific group but only when I am on the groups->group page where the .gjGroupUsersUser class exists. I need to get this number of users (var count) and update a text field when I am in the edit profile and the profile view. I hope it is a bit more clear now. The answer is different page

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Hearing this I'm thinking you should be looking into how **Groupjive** is getting this information on the page and utilize that. With a JavaScript solution, you'd have to actually visit Groups page first before going to the User profile page for it to work. But the backend of your CB has access to all these numbers that you need in an instant, and up-to-date. I would personally recommend getting in touch with the add-on builders and ask how you can get the user count in the input field by talking with the backend.

Comment: Thank you. It is an option in case in case I don't manage to implement it. That's the reason I posted it here. I believe that there must be a way. Will work a bit more on this. Thanks anyway

Comment: If nothing works out then come back and we'll try an implementation of your initial idea.